# Check if any error message exists and show all of them in laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

In laravel for showing all error messages at once i use the following code in the view

```
<?php 
 $something = $errors->all(); 
 if(!empty($something)): 
?>

<div class = "alert alert-error">                      
  @foreach ($errors->all('<p>:message</p>') as $input_error)
    {{ $input_error }}
  @endforeach 
</div> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

But when I want to use `$errors->all()` instead of `$something` in the if condition it's showing an error

> Can't use method return value in write context

Although the above code works fine, I think there may be a better ways to check if any error message exists and if it does then display it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, because you can't use any method as empty function parameter. From php docs:

> empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

What class is $errors? If it's your own class you can implement such method like 'isEmpty()' and then use in if statement:

```
if ($errors->isEmpty()) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was not aware of that!

Comment: Actually I have looked into the [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html#method_isEmpty) and there is already `$errors->isEmpty()` function implemented :)

Answer (score 28):

In my controller I use the following code to pass validation errors to my view:

```
return Redirect::to('page')
    ->withErrors($validator);
```

Then, in my view, I can use the following code to check if errors exist:

```
@if($errors->any())
<div id="error-box">
    <!-- Display errors here -->
</div>
@endif
```

You can also use `if($errors->all())`.

From the [Laravel (v4) docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#error-messages-and-views):

> Note that when validation fails, we pass the Validator instance to the
>   Redirect using the withErrors method. This method will flash the error
>   messages to the session so that they are available on the next
>   request... [A]n $errors variable will always be available in all of
>   your views, on every request, allowing you to conveniently assume the
>   $errors variable is always defined and can be safely used.

Comment: is there a  way to call $errors in controller, or I must find it in Session?

Comment: Only way I found to get it is like this: `$errors = Session::get('errors');`

Answer (score 2):

Best way in laravel is below code

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!-- /resources/views/post/create.blade.php -->

 <h2>Create Post</h2>
 @if ($errors->any())
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
 <ul>
 @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
 <li>{{ $error }}</li>
 @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).